# pulling file and zip while pulling in UNIX

Tags: shell, scp, mkfifo

I am generating files from netezza server using nzsql. Now the next part of the requirement is to zip and move the file into a different box (a second unix box). I can achieve this sitting in the 1st box (sitting in the first box I am first doing gzip and then moving the file using scp). But my question is, can this be done directly from the 2nd box. Means in the 1st box there will be the files which will be generated nzsql and in the 2nd box that file will be pulled and while pulling it will be zipped (using mkfifo or by any other means). In the 1st box I don't want the zip file to be created or resides. Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: don't know about your arch, but i think launching rsync periodically will solve your problem. any special and critical requirements?

Comment: Can you provide a small code snippet for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can in your box 2, have this running periodically:

```
rsync -azP user@box1:/path/to/your/sync/folder /dst/folder
```

the parameter explanation are directly copied from man page:

> -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
>
> -r, --recursive             recurse into directories
>
> -l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
>
> -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
>
> -D                          same as --devices --specials
>
> --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
>
> --specials              preserve special files
>
> -t, --times                 preserve modification times
>
> -o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
>
> -g, --group                 preserve group
>
> -z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer
>
> -P                          same as --partial --progress
>
> --partial               keep partially transferred files

but i doubt whether it's proper or not. you should push it from box1 to minimize the bandwidth usage. pulling is almost the same as polling.

reference here is a very complete tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps

Comment: Is it possible to sync. or migrate any specific file by giving a file name?

Comment: @KoushikChandra if you specify a file name it will sync the file only. but normally it doesn't make too much sense.